# Can sequences in music be modified rhythmically?

Tags: theory, composition, analysis

Can a sequence still be considered a sequence if the rhythm is changed?

For example:

Beethoven's Piano Sonata Op.13, II, in the left hand:

- The phrase beginning on the upbeat of 1 in the 3rd measure and ending on beat 1 of the next measure
- The same phrase a third lower with the rhythmic values doubled, starting on beat 2 of the 4th measure and ending on beat 1 of the 6th measure

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to disagree here a little bit.  I'm not going to offer an in-depth analysis of the Beethoven because I will present my answer in general terms.

While [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_%28music%29) of a sequence asserts that it is the "immediate restatement of a motif or longer melodic (or harmonic) passage at a higher or lower pitch in the same voice[,]" this definition is incomplete and not necessarily correct.

A sequence can be in any number of voices.  Sequences can happen simultaneously, and they do not have to be part of the melody.  You could have an accompaniment that is a sequence.

Essentially, **a sequence is a motivic element that repeats**.  This motive does not have to be related to the melody, or even the accompaniment for that matter.  When stripped down, the only difference between a sequence and an ostinato is **motion.**

Where ostinati are typically static, sequences are usually rising or falling, jumping, or thickening (here the term "stretto" can be applied.)

To answer your question, yes, a sequence can be rhythmically modified.  The two terms for this are **augmentation** and **diminution.**  Augmentation is as it suggests - stretching or lengthening things out.  Diminution can then be reasoned to be a shortening of things.

Sequences can be stretched in terms of durational length, iterations of motive, or changes in orchestration to name a few, and they can be diminished in exactly the same ways as well.

That said, what you have pointed out in the excerpt in question is not a sequence.  It is not a motive.  It is really nothing more than rhythmic augmentation of a transposition creating a half-cadence between antecedent and consequent phrases.

This is a wonderful movement of a wonderful piece of music, but I don't think it is the most representative of a piece with abundant sequences.  Again, I will defer to J.S. Bach, the Sequence King.

Comment: +1. It came up in discussion that the hunt for sequences in the first 8 bars of this piece were at the behest of a Kostka/Payne workbook exercise--which I find to be a bit silly.

Comment: Agreed - that is very silly.

Comment: Why is that silly?